# display stacked cards in a row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to set up a row of cards for my home page by duplicating another card that I already have set up properly. When I tried to recreate it, I messed up my styling. The gray overlay isn't appearing and the card is zoomed in without me hovering over it. Would someone be able to explain what I did wrong, please?

(Code Snippet)
https://replit.com/@diknight55/snippet#index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you are looking for, but one thing I noticed from the example is that the card2-img-overlay class doesn't have the following styles (like the card-img-overlay class does):

```
.card2-img-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: var(--bs-card-img-overlay-padding);
    border-radius: var(--bs-card-inner-border-radius);
}
```

**Edit**

A better way to achieve what you want is to do the following change to your styles:

```
.row>* {
  flex: 1;
  ...
}
```

Also, for your 2nd card's li elements, change the "card2" class they have to "card1". Now that you are using the flex properly, you don't need the separate classes anymore. Then, change the "card2-img-overlay" classes of all the overlay divs to "card-img-overlay". Same as before, you don't need the separate class anymore.

After this the arrows should show up in the right place as well.

Then the only problem that remains is the button functionality. Now if you click any of the buttons, it transports the cards from stack2 to stack1.

To fix this, you should probably have separate classes "next1" and "next2" (as well as "prev1" and "prev2") for the buttons in the first and second stack respectively. Otherwise you are just overwriting the onclick function for the "next" and "prev" buttons. Also, don't reuse the lastCard variable, but rather use lastCard1 and lastCard2 for example. What's happening now is that when your site loads, it runs the javascript files and the last value you set to lastCard will stick. So then when any of the onclicks fires, it thinks that a card from stack2 is the lastCard regardless of which stack's buttons you click.

Comment: That's close. I'm trying to replicate the first card in a horizontal 2 x 4-row creating a total of eight cards and have it stacked as well. The first set of cards' buttons arent supposed to change the second set's when the button is clicked. They're all going to have their own individual set of buttons

Comment: Where does the 4 come from when you say 2x4 row? I think I get it that 2 is the number of stacks but I only see 3 cards per stack. Did you mean 2 x 3?

Comment: I think why your button changes the other set is because you use the same card variable in your javascript for both stacks and define an onclick function for the button with the 'next' class two times. You should probably have next1 and next2 for example and use card2 as the second variable (row 31). Same goes for prev, you should probably have prev1 and prev2.

Comment: To make the second stack look right, try to add `flex: 1` to `.row>*` and for the card2's li elements' classes change 'card2' to 'card1' (you can use the same styles now that you distribute the horizontal space evenly between the stacks)

Comment: That should also fix the button positions

Comment: And actually, you can also change the `card2-img-overlay` class for all the card2 overlays to be `card-img-overlay` now that you are using the flex property.

Comment: When you have done these fixes to the css and javascript, I think you should get what you wanted.

Comment: I updated the original answer to summarize all this

Comment: My apologies, I'm just now seeing this, as in 2 x 4 I meant two cards in a row, going down three more times

Comment: everything else works